# What's the difference between POINT(X,Y) and GeomFromText("POINT(X Y)")?

Tags: mysql, performance, spatial

I'd like to store some geometric positions in my MySQL database. For this I use the POINT datatype. Almost everywhere I read that the function `GeomFromText` should be used to insert data in the table.

However, I found out that `POINT(X,Y)` also works. I didn't find any description why `GeomFromText` should be used instead of `POINT`.

For example I have the following simple relation:

```
CREATE TABLE Site (
    SiteID      BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    Position    POINT
);
```

And I can insert values using the following two variants:

```
INSERT INTO Site (
    1,
    GeomFromText( 'POINT(48.19976 16.45572)' )
);

INSERT INTO Site (
    2,
    POINT(48.19976, 16.45572)
);
```

When I view the table (`SELECT * FROM Site`) I see the same binary blob for the location, and when I view the coordinates (`SELECT *, AsText(Position) FROM Site`) I also see the same values.

So why should GeomFromText be used? Are there any (known) performance differences between these two variants? How is this solved in other database systems than MySQL?

Comment: I don't know if there are any performance differences (I'd guess not but that's a guess only). But the second approach would be simpler when converting latitude and longitude values from another table. `INSERT INTO Site (Position) SELECT POINT(latitude, longitude) FROM tmp` is simpler than `...SELECT GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',latitude,' ',longitude,')' )) ...`

Comment: I also finde the second variant much simpler to construct, that's why I'm wondering that usually the first one is used almost everywhere where I've seen MySQL spatial extensions used.

Comment: I just tried inserting 10.000.000 locations in the table above (on my host) using both variants and didn't detect any measurable performance difference.

Comment: Please consider re-evaluating this in light of MySQL 8+ and for posterity: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227049/2639

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two different binary formats related to the MySQL spatial extensions, the ["well-known binary" (WKB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) format from the standards, and the MySQL internal `GEOMETRY` data type.

Prior to MySQL 5.1.35, functions like `POINT()` didn't return the MySQL internal data type; they returned WKB... so prior to then, you had to do this:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (pt_col) VALUES (GeomFromWKB(Point(1,2)));
```

But now, as in your example, this works:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (pt_col) VALUES(Point(1,2));
```

To the developers' credit, when they changed `Point()` and similar functions to (more sanely) return `GEOMETRY` objects, they allowed `GeomFromWKB()` and similar functions to actually accept either WKB or MySQL Geometry data as input even though the functions are intended to accept WKB as input.

The fact that the 1st method works (in spite of being technically wrong) on newer servers and the 2nd method doesn't work at all prior to MySQL 5.1.35 **might explain** why examples were written using the approach you've seen -- to avoid the issue entirely.  Otherwise... I've got nothing, here.

Concatenating and then parsing text seems intuitively slower and more error-prone than functions that accept proper variables as input, so I can't think of any reason to craft concatenated strings and use the text-based functions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-values.html#gis-wkb-functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-35.html

Comment: Thanks, interesting that this is only mentioned as a "footnote" in the release notes and nowhere in the documentation. So I'll stay away from the text based methods.

Comment: Why is it that 5 years later the MySQL docs still give examples of using the ST_GeomFromText() function when inserting? Is this answer still relevant? It a bit of confusing.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: @MattKieran WKB and WKT are standardized, open formats for expressing geospatial data. The examples use them because standards-oriented geospatial applications may already hold data in these formats, allowing MySQL to accept external geometries as a single argument to `ST_GeomFromText()` and similar conversion functions rather than requiring external applications to use the native SQL functions that construct geometry objects, which are found in the [Spatial Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-function-reference.html). The docs could be organized better.

Comment: Also @MattKieran this answer is only still relevant in the sense that it explains why older examples may be written contrary to what the docs indicate, any why MySQL works with the apparent type mismatches that using the functions this way would seem to indicate.  All three methods -- the native SQL functions, WKB (binary), or WKT (text) -- are valid.  What is not needed any more is convering the native function return values *from* WKB, because their return types are no longer WKB as they were many years ago.

Answer (score 7):

## MySQL 8+

For posterity the only thing that matters is that

- `Point(X,Y)` is a constructor for numbers with precision and does not require converting first to text making it faster. It's also guaranteed to **RETURN A `POINT` OR FAIL**. This makes it *strongly* typed if you want to think of it like that.
- [Well-Known text (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) constructors: these are *always* slower, as they require an addition step to parse the [Well-Known text (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). Note in older versions these could be found without the `ST_` prefix; where available, use the version with the `ST_` prefix. Use the WKT-constructors only if your input is already Well-known text. If not, use the `Point(x,y)` constructor above.

  - [`ST_GeomFromText(wkt, srid)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext) can return **ANY** spatial type that is supported by MySQL and can represented by WKT. This makes it *loosely* typed if you want to think of it like that.
  - [`ST_PointFromText(wkt, srid)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-pointfromtext) a strongly-typed `POINT`-constructor from Well-known text.

## Clarity

Skipping the history lesson, **NEVER** do `GeomFromText(Point(x,y))`. That's horrible, unsupported, and undocumented.

Answer (score -1):

With GeomFromText or any other *FromText function you can specify the [SRID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID). I don't think you can do it otherwise.

```
PointFromText('POINT(lat lng)', 4326)
```

Comment: This should be the other way around i.e. `POINT(lng lat)` instead of `POINT(lat lng)`

Comment: MySQL doesn't use SRIDs anyway. So that's pretty useless. If you need SRIDs, migrate to PostgreSQL / PostGIS.

Comment: MySQL 8 does use SRIDs. In fact, I am having trouble with a MySQL DB migrated from 5.7 to 8 precisely because of SRIDs.